# Excel-like behavior WPF textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to create a textbox which text binds an integer (e.g 123456789), but it shows the thousand separator (eg 123.456.789), but when I select the textbox for editing it the string returns without separator, until the textbox loses the focus, just like in Excel. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Trigger which formats the value if the TextBox isn't selected

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding SomeValue, StringFormat=N2}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding SomeValue}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

You can also use a Converter for formatting if you can't easily format with StringFormat

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly! Just one thing, Do you know how can i change the thousands separator from "," to "." directly in the xaml setter expression?
StackOverFlow Community, you are awesome :)

Comment: @GiacomoTagliabue You might have to use a `Converter` for that instead of `StringFormat`. Just format as normal then `.Replace()` the commas with dots

Comment: thank you, i didn't wanted to use `Converter`, but in this case it seems to be the only possibility

Comment: How I can use existing binding value instead of `SomeValue`? because all my textbox has existing value..

Answer (score 0):

one possibility:

you add a style which creates a trigger on IsFocused.
in the trigger you set a new template in which you have another formatting:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.Resources>
    <System:Double x:Key="boundDouble">1000</System:Double>
    <System:Double x:Key="boundDouble2">2000</System:Double>
  </Grid.Resources>
  <TextBox Width="100" Height="30">
    <TextBox.Text>
      <Binding Source="{StaticResource boundDouble}" Path="." StringFormat="{}{0:F3}" />
    </TextBox.Text>
    <TextBox.Style>
      <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Style.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Template">
              <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                  <TextBox>
                  <TextBox.Text>
                    <Binding Source="{StaticResource boundDouble}" Path="." StringFormat="{}{0:F5}" />
                  </TextBox.Text>
                  </TextBox>
                </ControlTemplate>
              </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
          </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
  </TextBox>
</Grid>
```