# IValueConverter not updating wpf TextBox

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm using IValueConverter to convert a double to string.  The string created by the converter is not displayed in a corresponding textbox.  For example, if a user enters 1.1 my value converter might format it as '1'.  However I still see '1.1' in the textbox.  I verified in debugger that the converter's Convert() method is called and that it returns '1'.  Am I missing something basic?

The converter's method is as follows:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    if (value is double && targetType == typeof(string))
    {
        string format = parameter == null ? "{0:F2}" : (string)parameter;
        string formatted = string.Format(format, value);
        return formatted;
    }
    return value.ToString();
}
```

The xaml is as follows:

```
<TextBox x:Name="balance" Grid.Row="12" Grid.Column="1" 
Text="{Binding Balance, Converter={StaticResource nullableConverter}, ConverterParameter=\{0:F0  \}, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="90" TextAlignment="Right" />
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you seeing binding errors in the output window at runtime?

Comment: No, I do not see any errors.

Comment: So you type in "1.1", tab out of the textbox to trigger the `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`, the `Balance` property in your DataContext updates to `1.1`, the converter code runs and converts `1.1` to `1`, and then the TextBox.Text still displays `1.1`? That shouldn't be the case... can you verify these exact steps in the order stated?

Comment: This is exactly what happens.  I just verified it.  Edit... I just realised that it is not as 'exact' as in your post.  I do not 'tab out' of the textbox. The update trigger kicks in on every change of the textbox content.

Comment: @bdristan Sorry I was a bit mistaken there, `UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus` is the default for TextBoxes which means you need to tab out of the box to update the data source, and you've changed it to `PropertyChanged`, which should trigger after every key pressed. That's probably related to why this is occurring. A better solution would be to leave the value unformated while the user is typing in it, and only apply the formatting after the `TextBox` loses focus. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8680879/302677) for an example

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a known issue with using a converter on `TextBox.Text` when `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`

This usually isn't an ideal solution because as the user types, the value gets converted, so this can cause confusion and unexpected results for the user.

For example, if the user types "1.1", and the value keeps getting truncated to "1" after each key press, the sequence of events would be:

- type <kbd>1</kbd>
- type <kbd>.</kbd>
- converter changes value to `1`
- type <kbd>1</kbd>
- value is now `11`

As a workaround, I usually recommend applying formatting only when the TextBox does not have focus using a Trigger, like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Balance, Converter={StaticResource nullableConverter}, ConverterParameter=\{0:F0  \}" />

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Balance, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your format item (stuff inside curly braces) is malformed.

Instead of

```
ConverterParameter=\{0:F0  \}
```

Try

```
ConverterParameter='{}{0:F0}  '
```

However, I wonder if setting `Binding.StringFormat` property wouldn't be enough? The conversion will be handled for you (forth and back) and you'll have validation working too (at least for the case when user inputs a non-number text).

Comment: The syntax of the parameter seems to be OK because I see it in the Convert() method as expected.  Also, the formatted result string in the method is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Make the binding two way so it flows in both directions.

Comment: TwoWay binding is default for `TextBox.Text`

Comment: I believe that by default it is two way.  I made it two way explicitly but it did not make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

It's only going to run that converter when the Binding object recognizes that the "Balance" property of your ViewModel has changed.

Does your ViewModel have both a public Getter and Setter?

If so, the Binding should be invoking the property setter on the ViewModel as the data in the textbox is changing.

Next, you need to signal back to the View (and the binding) that the property value has changed. Does your viewmodel implement INotifyPropertyChanged? Is your viewmodel raising the the PropertyChanged event (with PropertyName of "Balance") when the Balance setter is called?