# C# WPF ListBox Checkbox Binding IsChecked to a Field and IsSelected?

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, listbox

I'm trying to bind a CheckBox to a field but also trigger the checkbox's IsSelected.

Here is the ListBox setup that is working with the Binding to data

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstExclude"  Grid.Column="2" SelectionMode="Single" >
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <CheckBox  Content="{Binding Text}" 
          IsChecked="{Binding Checked ,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And here is the code associated with the binding

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    List<CheckBoxListItem> items1 = new List<CheckBoxListItem>();
    items1.Add(new CheckBoxListItem(true, “home”));
    items1.Add(new CheckBoxListItem(false, “work”));
    items1.Add(new CheckBoxListItem(true, “cell”));
    lstExclude.ItemsSource = items1;
}

public class CheckBoxListItem
{
   public bool Checked { get; set; }
   public string Text { get; set; }

   public CheckBoxListItem(bool ch, string text)
   {
     Checked = ch;
     Text = text;
    }
}
```

This binds the checkbox checked value correctly, but if I click the checkbox (checked or unchecked), I want it to select the item, so I tried doing it this way

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstExclude"  Grid.Column="2" SelectionMode="Single" >
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <CheckBox  Content="{Binding Text}" 
          IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}, Path=IsSelected}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

So this gives me the results of clicking the checkbox (check or uncheck) and it will select the item.  The problem is now the Checked field is not bound when I add the items.

How can you get the checkbox to be both bound to the Checked field AND still have the IsSelected work?

Comment: you can use a multibing and a MultiValueConverter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I answered my own question (and there might better to do this so feel free to add)  I added a Click event to the checkbox like so

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstExclude"  Grid.Column="2" SelectionMode="Single" >
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <CheckBox  Content="{Binding Text}" 
          IsChecked="{Binding Checked ,Mode=TwoWay}" Click="CheckBox_Click"/>
      </DataTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

and then added this code for the Click Event

```
private void CheckBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var cb = sender as CheckBox;
    var item = cb.DataContext;
    lstExclude.SelectedItem = item;
}
```

Now the item gets selected when you click the checkbox (checked or unchecked)  and the item is available to the 'lstExclude.SelectedIndex' method

I hope this helps anybody coming along with the same problem.

Answer (score 14):

Would it work to bind both UI properties to the `Checked` object model property?

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Checked, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <CheckBox Content="{Binding Text}" IsChecked="{Binding Checked}"/>
   </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Actually, there is a problem (and it's because of my wording of my question) - I want the item to be selected whenever you click the checkbox (regardless if it's checked or not) - Sorry. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: @user3573191 In the past I've used a `DataTrigger` that sets `IsSelected="True"` whenever `IsKeyboardFocusWithin` is equal to true. The syntax looks something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8680879/302677). Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Rachel I have the same issue and tried using a DataTrigger, but the Setter Property is being resolved as property of ListBoxItem which doesn't have IsChecked property

Comment: @Shekhar The `.Checked` property of the data model is being bound to both the `ListBoxItem.IsSelected` and `CheckBox.IsChecked` properties. If you're trying to write a trigger for `ListBoxItem`, use the `IsSelected` property. And if that still doesn't work, post a new question with the details of your code and feel free to leave me a link and I'll take a look at it :)

Comment: @Rachel my property on the code side is called IsSelected an I was mixing  it up with IsChecked. My code works now , only half a day wasted.

Answer (score 2):

you can use a `MultiBinding` with `MultiConverter`

```
<CheckBox.IsChecked>
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource YourMultiBindConverter}"> 
                <Binding Path="IsSelected" RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}"/> 
                <Binding Path="Checked"/> 
 </MultiBinding> 
</CheckBox.IsChecked>
```

and create a **YourMultiBindConverter** that implement IMultiValueConverter

Comment: Actually, there is a problem (and it's because of my wording of my question) - I want the item to be selected whenever you click the checkbox (regardless if it's checked or not) I updated the question - Sorry. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: This actually helped me out a lot as I didn't need to bind to a specific value in my model, but a list of values. My client wanted the listbox to show checks as well as highlights, and this helped me get there. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
 <CheckBox Padding="10" 
           IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type  
                                                 ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}">
        <CheckBox.LayoutTransform>
                  <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
        </CheckBox.LayoutTransform>
  </CheckBox>
```